# Multiple series in highstocks

Tags: highcharts, series

```
trade = [
[1597622400000, 0.5542]
[1597622400000, 0.3899]
[1597622400000, 0.2109]
[1597622400000, 0.1645],

[1597708800000, 0.5124]
[1597708800000, 0.3321]
[1597708800000, 0.2111]
[1597708800000, 0.1837],

[1597795200000, 0.6635]
[1597795200000, 0.3956]
[1597795200000, 0.2322]
[1597795200000, 0.3455]
]
```

I want to create a high stocks chart for data of this format. I need to create four series for data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3] (I need to plot 4 points each day.) I can recreate the data as [[1597622400000, [0.5542, 0.3899, 0.2109,  0.1645] , [1597708800000, [0.5124, 0.3321,  0.2111, 0.1837], [1597795200000, [0.6635, 0.3956, 0.2322, 0.3455]] if required.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'trade fall,        
        data: trade, 
        dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: 'sum',
        units: [[groupingUnit, [1]]]
                    }
            }],
```

Any ideas on how can I plot this? or any links to the corresponding JS fiddle?

Please share any ideas on how can I format the data or any changes in the series. I can try recreating the data as suggested. The main aim is to plot 4 points each day.

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you are able to recreate your data and keep each day in one array, like here:

```
var trade = [
  [
    [1597622400000, 0.5542],
    [1597622400000, 0.3899],
    [1597622400000, 0.2109],
    [1597622400000, 0.1645],

  ],
  [
    [1597708800000, 0.5124],
    [1597708800000, 0.3321],
    [1597708800000, 0.2111],
    [1597708800000, 0.1837],
  ],
  [
    [1597795200000, 0.6635],
    [1597795200000, 0.3956],
    [1597795200000, 0.2322],
    [1597795200000, 0.3455],
  ]
];
```

Then you can easily add your data to the chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/obahzwL3/

```
var data1 = trade.map(d => d[0]),
  data2 = trade.map(d => d[1]),
  data3 = trade.map(d => d[2]),
  data4 = trade.map(d => d[3]);


// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: data1
  }, {
    data: data2
  }, {
    data: data3
  }, {
    data: data4
  }]
});
```

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks for your suggestion. But, what if the number of points are dynamic. In this case, I can plot for 4 points. But in some cases there may be 3 points, 5 points and even 7 points. How to handle cases like those?

Comment: Your requirement was totally different - `(I need to plot 4 points each day.)`. In the case of an unknown number of points and series you will need to implement some logic which will find how many points is per day, next loop through this amount and create a series data for each day. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tkvd3g1x/